# How to create a text box in PPT that makes a 90 degree angle, to go around the perimeter of rectangle?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, text-formatting

I know how to change direction of text, and can create 'word art' that is in the shape of a circle. But I'm looking to have text that will go all the way around the perimeter of a rectangle. So if you were holding a rectangle, you'd turn it 90 degrees, then another 90, etc. and could read the entire text.  Possible?  I am stumped.

Answer (score 1):

There's no automatic way to do this in PPT, but you can add a text box at the top of the rectangle, type into it until it hits the right side of the rectangle, then add another text box, rotate it 90 degrees clockwise, snug it up against the right side of the rectangle, type into it until it hits the bottom of the rectangle and so on.  Original text box, then three more, each rotated 90 clockwise from the previous.